# How do I decompose multiple time series (columns) at once?

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet containing the following data: 144 columns with names as headers and 729 values (returns over time) - see picture. I managed through the ts and decompose function to decompose one column (if file is only one column). How do I decompose every column separately when reading the whole file at once? So I get every seasonal component for every column separately at once. I cannot find a way to either do the whole sheet at once or choosing only one column.

My Data:

[image: spread sheet]

Output in R:

[image: Output]

Output Plot in R:

[image: Output Plot]

As a final step i let R deduct the seasonality from the original data:

[image: Output Final]

My commands so far:

```
ts_svi = ts(svi, frequency = 7)
decompose_svi = decompose(ts_svi, type = "additive")
adjust_svi=ts_svi - decompose_svi$seasonal
adjust_svi
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input data and the expected output?

Comment: I edited the question - hope that gives you an idea

Comment: Have a look at `lapply()`, which would allow you to apply commands to each column of your data frame.

Comment: the problem is when I enter the commands for decompose R simply thinks my data is not sorted by column but rather every line equals a year or so. so it doesn't run the command on each column separately but rather on the whole thing giving me one output for everything

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and solve it by using lapply over the names of the series (it must be specified):

```
colnames(ts) <- someNames

ts_dec <- lapply(colnames(ts), function(x) {decompose(ts[, x], type = "additive")})
```

Or, using the names of your objects:

```
decompose_svi <- lapply(colnames(ts_svi), function(x) {decompose(ts_svi[, x], type = "additive")})
```

The result will be some big list, but you would be able to acces all the seasonal figures. Hope it helps.